# Code is not finding the element in table using python behave BDD

Tags: python, automation, bdd

My code is not finding element in the table and not updating its duration

i am trying to get a element from the list and want to edit its duration but this code is not working and not finding the element from the list and updating its duration

@then('I get the data of elements with class "gantt_tree_content"')
def step_update_end_date(context):
element_list = context.driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "gantt_tree_content")

```
task_exists = False
for element in element_list:
    res = "Task by SK-1"
    if element.text == res:
        task_exists = True
        column = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "duration-column")
        column.click()
        edit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='duration']")

        edit.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
        edit.send_keys("6")
        edit.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        break
```